# CakePHP - Cannot redeclare class conflicting with 3rd party library

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I'm working with an application in CakePHP 2.5.4 and trying to integrate a third party library to work with a video service. The library is here: https://github.com/vzaar/vzaar-api-php

I've copied the above library to app/Vendor/vzaar/

In one of my applications controllers, app/Controller/VideosController.php, I'm including it using:

`require_once APP . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'vzaar' . DS . 'Vzaar.php';`

Whenever I run any of it's functions I get a PHP Fatal error:
 
**Error: Cannot redeclare class User**

The library has classes such as User.php and Video.php. My application also has classes with these names.

So is the solution to rename them in the library? Or have I imported/used this in the wrong way? Renaming things seems a very convoluted way around this, although I understand the issue is the same class name can't be used in multiple places.

I've searched on here and Google for a solution but haven't found anything. I would imagine this is a fairly common issue since it's likely any OOP-PHP classes from third parties might share the same names as class names in a Cake application?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is the solution to rename them in the library?

Yes. I would fork the library on Github and create a namespaced version of it. I'm surprised they haven't used namespaces. If this was intentionally then they should have prefixed the classes with something like `Vzaar_`, which was a common practice before namespaces became common. Bottom line is the vendor made a not so smart decision, especially because "User" and "Video" a *very* common names. Add namespaces, do a pull request, maybe they'll accept it.